# Using RRD4J and XML to create graph?

Tags: rrdtool

I have a homework that I need to research RRD4J and create graph by using RRD4J library. My teacher just gave me only xml file. So, can I use XML with RRD4J to draw graph and how?

Answer (score 1):

Without much more information it is difficult to answer your question. Those general steps might help you to understand what you should do, to solve the problem:

1) Depending on the granularity you would like to have (and the data frequency you have in XML file) create RRD

For example if you would like to have hourly and daily data, your archive creation should look like:

```
RrdDef rrdDef = new RrdDef(fileName, 60); // 60 is step, means you expect data to enter at 60 seconds interval
rrdDef.setStartTime(...); // Set initial timestamp here (must be 10 digit epoch timestamp) 
rrdDef.addDatasource(DATASOURCE_NAME, DsType.GAUGE, 120, 0, Double.NaN); // DATASOURCE_NAME is the name of your variable in time series, DsType - is the type of data (always increasing, increasing and decreasing, etc), 120 is the timeout for new data entry, (i.e if no data enters in 120 seconds, NaN will be added to database), max and min values 
rrdDef.addArchive(ConsolFun.AVERAGE, 0.99, 1, 60);
rrdDef.addArchive(ConsolFun.AVERAGE, 0.99, 24, 240);

RrdDb rrdDb = new RrdDb(rrdDef);
rrdDb.close();
```

(all of those configurations are coming from detailed analisys of time series you are working with, it's really hard to predict something without looking at data)

2) Parse XML file using SAX (I guess this one will be better since after insertiong into RRD database you won't need to access parsed values anymore)

3) While parsing XML, update RRD

```
RrdDb rrdDb = new RrdDb(fileName);
Sample sample = rrdDb.createSample();
sample.setAndUpdate(timestamp+":"+value);
rrdDb.close();
```

4) When all data is inserted generate some graphs (check the examples and options on RRD4J website)

P.S(use the intergration with MongoDB, which outperformes RRD4J many time, there is an example also on their page)

Hope this helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is this XML a template ?
http://rrd4j.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/org/rrd4j/core/XmlTemplate.html

The best configuration for rrd4j is File and version 2 rrd.